# How to whitelist HTTP(S) requests from SNS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, https, amazon-sns

I want to subscribe my application's HTTP(S) endpoint to SNS. But my application restricts which IP addresses can make requests to it.

**Update**: My application is running in AWS VPC and restricts IP addresses with security groups.

As I read in this article, I think I need whitelist all AWS's IP address.
https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/sns-ip-address-range

Is this a good approach? Or is there another way to allow SNS to send HTTP(S) requests to my application?

Comment: Does your application run in AWS, or external to Amazon?

Comment: Is your app running on AWS? How is the app restricted? inside a VPC with security groups?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information. My application is running in AWS and restricts IP addresses with security groups.